# Gevent is in an unsupported or invalid wheel

Tags: python, macos, gevent, osx-elcapitan

I try on my osX (el capitan) to install Odoo.
Then i've download the package and when I try to install the 3rf party lib with `pip install -r requirements.txt`, it gives me:

```
gevent is in an unsupported or invalid wheel
```

Any idea ?
Xcode is installed, the command line tools too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Impossible to install gevent via pip then according to the official doc, i've used:

```
pip install cython git+git://github.com/gevent/gevent.git#egg=gevent
```

and it works

Comment: Same problem here on El Capitan. This works, thanks!